# What if as a Github student I ran out of private repositories?

Tags: github

I have 5 free private repositories through the student pack. If I use them up can I turn one of them to public and turn another one private? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year since I've tried this, but yes, you can. If you need more, however, you might want to consider [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-in-the-cloud), which is not as popular as GitHub but does offer unlimited private repos for free for small teams. I use it for private code and simply create a public repo on GitHub to transfer the code to if I decide to make it public.